# Riemann Steiltjes Integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I have been stuck with this problem for a few hours. So far I have tried to prove that b- 1/n tends to b when n tends to infinity.

Let be $\alpha,\ f,\:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ continous, such that f is Riemann Stieltjes Integrable

Show $[\int_a^{b-1/n}f\ d\alpha]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\to \int_a^b f\, d\alpha$.

Comment: Use the fact that $f$ is bounded and note that $\int_{a} ^{b} f\, d\alpha - \int_{a} ^{b-1/n}f\,d\alpha=\int_{b-1/n}^{b}f\,d\alpha$

Comment: I understand that. But how is it that the finite partitions of 1/n tend to that redult

Comment: use the continuity of $\alpha$

Comment: How? Should I take the difference between the $\alpha(b)-\alpha(b-1/n)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy case is where $\alpha$ monotone. Assume  WLOG that $\alpha $ is non-decreasing.  The integrand $f$ is continuous and, hence, bounded with $|f(x)| \leqslant M$ for $x \in [a,b]$.  Hence,

$$0 \leqslant \left|\int_{b-1/n}^b f \, d\alpha  \right| \leqslant M[\alpha(b) - \alpha(b-1/n)]$$

Since $\alpha $ is continuous we have by the squeeze theorem,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{b-1/n}^b f \, d\alpha  = 0,$$

and the desired result follows from the additivity property of the integral,

$$\int_{b-1/n}^b f \, d\alpha  + \int_a^{b-1/n} f \, d\alpha   = \int_a^b f \, d\alpha  $$

A more general and difficult case is where we only have that $\alpha$ is of bounded variation.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any partition $P = (x_0,x_1, \ldots,x_m)$  with $\|P\| < \delta$ we have for any corresponding RS-sum

$$\left| \int_{b-1/n}^b f \, d\alpha - \sum_{j=1}^mf(\xi_j)[\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})] \right| < \epsilon,  $$

which implies

$$\left| \int_{b-1/n}^b f \, d\alpha \right| < \epsilon + \sum_{j=1}^m|f(\xi_j)|\,|\alpha(x_j) - \alpha(x_{j-1})| \leqslant \epsilon +M V_{b-1/n}^b(\alpha). $$

Since $\alpha $ is continuous it can be shown with some effort (proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2842348/148510)) that the total variation function $x \to V_{x}^b(\alpha) $ is also continuous. Hence, $V_{b-1/n}^b(\alpha) \to V_b^b(\alpha) = 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and for every $\epsilon > 0$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{b-1/n}^b f \, d\alpha  \leqslant \epsilon,$$

which implies that again

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{b-1/n}^b f \, d\alpha  = 0$$

The most difficult case is where $\alpha$ has unbounded variation yet the RS-integral exists, but the first two cases cover what is usually considered for RS-integrals.

Comment: I am still unable to prove the case you mention at the end. Do you have a reference for its proof?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Not yet.  I thought I might have a counterexample but this proved to be incorrect.